# При попытке зайти на instagram под прокси, не прогружаются видео, фотки постов, истории, а также фото профилей

Tags: python, proxy, instagram

Не для кого ни секрет что инстаграм не работает в России. Я реализую парсер на основе python + selenium. Разрабатывая и тестируя я использовал VPN и получал весь контент как он есть на сайте, но при попытки использовать прокси начиналось бесконечно грузится видео или истории, и не загружаются фотографии. Я пробовал частные прокси Бельгии и Италии.

Далее, я решил сделать проверку проксей не на webdriver selenium'a, а на обычном браузере результат тот же - контент не прогружается.

Мой проект потом будет работать на сервере(в России), и мне нужно предусмотреть смену ip-адресса. В чем может быть проблема и как это исправить? Или каким способом я могу еще менять ip-адресс?

Answer (score 1):

Такая же ерунда и в моем приложении из России, которое работает с 2017 года.. без безголовых браузеров - через заголовки и куки на php. А с декабря перестал загружаться именно медиаконтент через прокси (т.к. из России без прокси никак).. перепробовал кучу разных - текстовая инфа загружается нормально, а картинки и видео нет. Принял временное решение арендовать забугорный VPS/VDS сервер, на нем установил все необходимое, установил 3Proxy - такая же ерунда - картинки не грузятся. В итоге решил сделать без прокси - просто через этот сервер перенаправляю все запросы с контентом - в итоге все летает шустро, быстрее чем с какими либо проксями. Но проблема остается с периодичными блокировками аккаунтов... если раньше аккаунта хватало на 3-4 часа, то сейчас блочится уже через 20-30 минут.. нужно либо парсер переписывать, либо пробовать использовать какой-нибудь Puppeteer...

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]